# Overlapping views with elevation

Tags: android, layout, overlapping

Do you know how menu layout similar to the one in new Google Tasks app could be achieved?

I am mainly trying to create a white bar with a button overlapping between that white bar and recycler view.

I managed to get that overlapping to work, but as soon as I would add elevation to the bottom white bar (LinearLayout in my case), button goes behind it. Giving higher elevation to the button does nothing.

Do you know how this effect could be achieved?

[image: Google Tasks App]

Comment: can you share a your xml?

Comment: I have the same problem: the view with greater elevation after BottomNavigationView also goes behind.

Comment: I have redesigned my app and there is no longer need to for but would be interesting to learn how to achieve this effect.